# Como fazer um efeito fade em ícones usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Preciso de uma ajuda queria fazer uns ícones animados no site, precisava de um efeito de FADE, que quando passa-se o mouse em cima do ícone ele troca a imagem suavemente.

## [Site de exemplo](http://vasterad.com/themes/astrum/)

Nos ícones do site  `:Flexible`, `Responsive` e
`Retina` `Ready`

Alguém sabe algum exemplo na internet?

Answer (score 5):

Efeito `fadeIn()` e `fadeOut()` mexe apenas com o `opacity` do elemento. Você terá que fazer a troca da imagem.

O que você pode fazer é ao passar o mouse manda um `FadeOut()` na imagem altera ela e manda um `fadeIn()`

### HTML

```
<div id="imgHover"><img src="imagem.png"/></div>
```

### Jquery

```
$('#imgHover img').hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000).attr('src','imagem2.png').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: lionbtt você disse exatamente o que eu quero mas testei seu código aqui mas não pegou pra trocar de imagem no hover, tem como você me ajudar.

Comment: Deu algum erro? o fadein e out funcionou e soh não trocou a img, ou não fez efeito nenhum?

Answer (score 2):

É possivel fazer isso usando apenas css, através de [trasitions](http://tableless.com.br/transition-e-animation/):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="circle">
  <i class="icon-wrench"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://vasterad.com/themes/astrum/css/icons.css);


.circle{
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f89;
}

.circle:hover{
    background: #ff8;
}


.circle i{
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 37%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.circle:hover i{
    color: red ;
}
```

**[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/RNQLd/1/)**

Comment: Bem legal! Não conhecia essa propriedade do CSS. Porém, ele disse que queria trocar a imagem, então não seria apenas o alterar o `color` do `background`, teria que alterar o `backgroud-image`.

Comment: Sim, mas fica a critério dele alterar no seu código. Nesse caso, sim, pode usar uma imagem como background.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda de todos mas o CSS3 do Jefferson Alison me ajudo muito, valeu.

Comment: Por nada, só marque a resposta como correta :)